# Magento remove param and redirect to same url

Tags: magento

I want to remove some URL parameter (like utm_source, but whatever), put it in session and redirect to same page with URL clean of this specific param

I've done in controller_front_init_before like this:

```
$frontController = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
$params = $frontController->getRequest()->getParams();
$myParams = array("b");
foreach($myParams as $myParam) {
    if (isset($params[$myParam])) {
        $customerSession->setData(
            $myParam, $params[$myParam]
        );
        unset($params[$myParam]);
    }
}
$frontController->getRequest()->setParams($params); // <- I don't know what to do with that
```

Now what is the best method to redirect to the same page in request ?

For example redirect http://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3 to http://example.com?a=1&c=3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$frontController = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
$params = $frontController->getRequest()->getParams();
$shouldRedirect = false

foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'b') {
        $customerSession->setData($key, $value);   
    }
    else{
       unset($params[$key]);
       $shouldRedirect = true;
    }
}

if($shouldRedirect){
    //$url = get url and redirect
    //see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/add-query-parameters-to-an-existing-url-string
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);       
}
```

Comment: yes, $shouldRedirect flag is necessary - otherwise it will loop, I noticed.
I think there's a way to get the instance of current reuqest url, set new params and redirect, without need to construct a new  with Mage::getUrl()